# silverlight WCF crossdomain/clientaccesspolicy policy

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I am having problem with the WCF + Silverlight application when querying database.

An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.

at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at AWShop.EmployeeServiceProxy.GetEmployeesCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at AWShop.Services.EmployeeDataService.b__0(Object s, GetEmployeesCompletedEventArgs ea)
   at AWShop.EmployeeServiceProxy.EmployeeServiceClient.OnGetEmployeesCompleted(Object state)

I have my project structure as follows:

MainSolution
- SilverlightApplication (Service reference to WCF is added here and its hosted in IIS 7.5)
- DAL (LINQ2SQL)
- WCF
- Web (hosting silverlight app) (Hosted in IIS 7.5)

I have following clientaccesspolicy setup in my solution (root of web project and I tried at adding to every other project as well but no luck)

I also have tried using crossdomain.xml but still does not work.

The webservice itself http://localhost/AWShop.WCF/EmployeeService.svc works fine.

Any help is much appreciated its bit frustrating to hanged on to this problem.

Many thanks,
Preyash

Comment: just use Fiddler2 (www.fiddler2.com) to check where the client looks for clientaccesspolicy.xml and then put it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to deploy clientaccesspolicy.xml at the root of the web server

Comment: exactly, clientaccesspolicy.xml must be at the root of the web server

Comment: I have placed the file at awshop.web/clientaccesspolicy.xml which I belive is at the root of webserver?